# How to manage an already known printer?

Tags: android, printing

I don't really understand how to manage printers in `PrintService`in Android.

I'm talking about Bluetooth printer in my case.

The [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/printservice/package-summary.html) seems to explain how to manage a new printer so in that case I understand that I have to put my printer in discovery mode and make a call to `onStartPrinterDiscovery`.

But know what to do if I already discovered a printer, for which I stored its address in my shared preferences?

I see that when an application try to print on my printer, Android make a call to `onStartPrinterDiscovery` and here I wouldn't like to put printer in discovery mode and launch the discovery session as I own its address and can directly make a `connect`.

But Android complains that the printer is not available. What do I miss here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/printservice/PrinterDiscoverySession.html):

> Discovered printers are added by invoking addPrinters(List). Added printers that disappeared are removed by invoking removePrinters(List). Added printers whose properties or capabilities changed are updated through a call to addPrinters(List). The printers added in this session can be acquired via getPrinters() where the returned printers will be an up-to-date snapshot of the printers that you reported during the session. Printers are not persisted across sessions.

So as you discover printers, you call addPrinters (at this point with no attributes)

> If the system is interested in being constantly updated for the state of a printer you will receive a call to onStartPrinterStateTracking(PrinterId) after which you will have to do a best effort to keep the system updated for changes in the printer state and capabilities. You also must update the printer capabilities if you did not provide them when adding it, or the printer will be ignored. When the system is no longer interested in getting updates for a printer you will receive a call to onStopPrinterStateTracking(PrinterId).

once the user selects a printer you reported, you should get and update the printer attributes. If you do not do so, you will see "This printer is not available" in the print preview.
I don't think you should be storing the discovered printers in your shared preferences as they shouldn't persist between sessions unless you're trying to cache the attributes of printers you've tracked.

Comment: not sure I well explained my problem; When I start my `PrintService`, then I discover the device, I connect to it so I see it in the printer list and I can print to it. Now later when I restart my device, the printer still powered on, I try to print on it and at that time, Android tells me that the printer is not available.  I can see, debugging my service that `onStartPrinterDiscovery` is called but Is it necessary to discover the printer again ?? Isn't it possible to include it back in the printers list and get it available immediately?

Comment: Yes it is necessary, as in the quote above "Printers are not persisted across sessions.". This makes sense because the printer may be available now but may be powered off tomorrow, or may be out of range or ... etc. In every session you need to re-discover and report the printers. Did I understand your question correctly?

Comment: anyway I don't really understand why we have to do that. Think about a handsfree set, maybe it's online, maybe not. If it is, I connect it directly, thanksfully I don't have to search for it everytime I take my car!